# join query does not return null values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this table with units/homes

```
CREATE TABLE `units` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cancellation_policy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UKha7gwhuig6p6vftvoghfi2b7g` (`title`,`image_url`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_pdd7pto9vch2kb58kohy96a5f` (`image_url`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_58rre8c1gk28a7d5p6wguiti9` (`title`)
)
```

and this one with reviews

```
CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stars` int NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `unit_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UKc3rd8vjkpbcda34jomifuybu9` (`user_id`,`unit_id`),
  KEY `FKbgbdator49pjrbriaktrbv1q2` (`unit_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKbgbdator49pjrbriaktrbv1q2` FOREIGN KEY (`unit_id`) REFERENCES `units` (`id`)
)
```

and I want to get all movies together with the average rating. However this query does not return me back movies without ratings (NULL) values. This query does not return movies without ratings

```
select 
u.id, u.cancellation_policy, u.description, u.image_url, u.price, u.region, u.title, round(avg(stars),0) as ratings 
from units u
inner join
reviews r
ON u.id = r.unit_id 
group by u.id
```

What is the correct way to get all movies including those w/o stars?

Comment: What does *without ratings* mean, there is no column `ratings`?

Comment: Please update your question to a minimal reproductible example to help others understand your question better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LEFT JOIN would show you all units even those that have no reviews

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.cancellation_policy,
    u.description,
    u.image_url,
    u.price,
    u.region,
    u.title,
    ROUND(AVG(IFNULL(stars,0)), 0) AS ratings
FROM
    units u
        LEFT JOIN
    reviews r ON u.id = r.unit_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `INNER JOIN`